# Symplectic state-transition matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, symplectic-geometry, symplectic-linear-algebra

I'm reading article about Hamiltonian's system.
They defined Hamiltonian's equations as a matrix
$$ \mathbf{\dot{\eta}} = \mathbf{J} \frac{\partial H(\mathbf{\eta},t)}{\partial \mathbf{\eta}},  $$
where $\mathbf{J}$ is standard symplectic matrix 
$$ \mathbf{J} = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & \mathrm{1}\\ 
\mathrm{-1} & 0
\end{bmatrix}. $$
Later, they said that state-transition matrix $\Phi$ for this equation is
$$ \mathbf{\dot{\Phi}}  = \mathbf{J} \frac{\partial ^2H}{\partial \mathbf{\eta^2}} \mathbf{\Phi}$$
I read something about state-transition matrix but I have no idea how the second equation came from the first one. Can somebody explain it?

Thanks for help!

Comment: What's the article?

Comment: @RicardoBuring, here is tle [link](https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/tjsass/53/180/53_180_105/_pdf). It's on the second page.